# How to use firebase as login authentication for node.js in middleware?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, passport.js

I recently learned about node.js and firebase, and I tried to use firebase login for my node.js application. so sorry if my question is too boring :)
I have tried the tutorial from the following page, but it still can't be run on my application, (https://www.codementor.io/victornwaiwu/using-firebase-as-an-authenticating-middleware-in-express-js-5z435fvaz)
is there a suggestion where should I start learning? and are there examples of applications that I can try?

best regard

Comment: I would start with the firebase docs. And also specify what you mean my "can't be run on my application".  Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest rather than going through a written tutorial, it's best if you refer to a video.
You can refer to the following links given below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kRgVxULbag

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP4Tr0l08NE